# If condition inside my route provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my `$routeProvider` I have something like this,

```
$routeProvider.when('/person/:name/:label', { ...
```

What I want to do is add a special case that will help me display a different template if `:name`, for example, equal with 'John'.

What I tried was using something like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/person/:name/:label', {
  templateUrl: function(param) {
    if(param=='John') {
      return 'john.html'; 
    }
     return 'generic.html';
  }, 
  controller: 'PersonCtrl'
});
```

I keep getting `generic.html` though. How can I access the name variable and fix this issue?

Comment: Use `param.name` instead of `param` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params object passed into the templateUrl function is access just like $routeParams. So just as you would in $routeParams, you need to use the dot operator to access the provisioned property. So in your case, it's `params.name`

```
$routeProvider.when('/person/:name/:label', {
  templateUrl: function(params) {
    return params.name == 'John' ? 'john.html' : 'generic.html';
  },
  controller: 'PersonCtrl'
});
```

Comment: Trying to add routeParams the following way
`.config(['$routeProvider', '$routeParams', function($routeProvider, $routeParams) {` gives me an `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParams` Error.

Comment: I see you marked it as correct after the comment, everything working now?

Comment: You needn't use the `$routeParams` object to access parameters in a `templateUrl` function. As per [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), your templateUrl function will be passed a an Array of supplied parameters, so you just need `params.name`.

Comment: No I still have the problem. But its probably something that has to do with the way I am trying to import routeParams, hence my error, and not yours.

Comment: @MykWillis you are indeed correct one can access the various route parameters that way.

Comment: I think Myk is actually more correct here. You weren't accessing the param id with the dot operator, but instead just trying to access param. In your code snippet, param itself is actually an instance of $routeParams, so just as you would say $routeParams.name, you can also say params.name

Comment: I will modify my answer to reflect the simpler approach. However, I think Myk should post and have it marked correct if he wants.

Comment: Indeed. The thing is that I had done something similar before for a route with only one parameter and had worked, but I was not sure what I was doing, and embarrassed to say so.